# How to extract a linked text from a div using scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the sample code:

Category1

As a new user of python, I am not finding the CSS selector for extracting the category name.

What is the CSS selector to get the category name?
I am using scrapy and beautifulsoup to scrape data from the site.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.